# Why my app stop working when I open many chrome tabs?

Tags: android, android-service

I am developing a simple app that just play a sound in background until is killed by the user. The problem is that when I open many more than 30-40 tabs in chrome, it stop playing the sound and I need to reopen the app.

My smartphone has only 1Gb of RAM but I have noticed that many music players do work even if I open more than 100 tabs in chrome.

This is the code:

**PlayerService.class:**

```
public class PlayerService extends Service
{
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
        Log.i("PROVA SERVICE", "Distruzione Service");
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    }

    public void play(View v)
    {

        startService(new Intent(this, PlayerService.class));
    }

    public void stop(View v)
    {

        stopService(new Intent(this, PlayerService.class));
    }
...
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="Play!" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="play"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView android:text="Stop!" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="stop"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have obviously added the service in the manifest:

```
<service android:name="PlayerService"/>
```

So, what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For API level 5 or later you can use the [startForeground()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) method to start your Service in the foreground.

The document says

> Make this service run in the foreground, supplying the ongoing
>   notification to be shown to the user while in this state. By default
>   services are background, meaning that if the system needs to kill them
>   to reclaim more memory (such as to display a large page in a web
>   browser), they can be killed without too much harm. You can set this
>   flag if killing your service would be disruptive to the user, such as
>   if your service is performing background music playback, so the user
>   would notice if their music stopped playing.

Comment: Yes you are correct, but it can be terminated by the system anyway. If a service runs on foreground you have to notify a user by setting a  notification in a toolbar.

Comment: Usually it wont kill the app immediately

Answer (score 1):

It happens because your device have no enough memory and kill all background services. Try to start your service in foreground modeusing method startForeground();